# Suggested edits fools me

Tags: bug, review

About 10 times today, I have clicked on the review icon with the red dot. There's always a suggested edit review pending. When I click on it, each time it told me that the review queue has already been cleared.

Can't that button update itself when the queue is cleared? It's so annoying that I am fored to write this Meta post for it.

Just happened again, so I could take screenshots:

The icon:

[image: Review icon draws attention]

Suggested edits need care:

[image: Suggested edits need care]

Fooled!

[image: Review queue has been cleared]

Comment: I encourage you to post this at http://meta.stackexchange.com as it is something SE should probably improve.

Answer (score 4):

The sneaky thing here is that it *wasn't* cleared - the text lies. You simply already reviewed all the items you could (and weren't eligible for some, like a bunch of tag wiki suggestions I just cleared out).

These ones you couldn't review for one reason or another were still active review tasks that we need help with... but you can't help with them. It's definitely irritating that it asks.

An old, but still reasonably accurate, meta post: [What does the number next to the review link in the top bar actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251914/215468)

> - In the topbar you see all available reviews site wide (excluding close votes on SO)
> - on /review you see the number of tasks available for you personally.